# Problem with unpacking zip archive with UTF-8 file names in OS X if zip was made in Windows

Tags: windows, macos, encoding, zip, utf-8

I have packed my files in Windows 7 using Total Commander asking to use UTF-8 for file names. Then I tried to unpack my files in OS X, but Cyrillic names were messed. I have tried most programs -- none has helped me, so I had to use Parallels with Windows and Total Commander to get what I want.

Is there any other way to do it? Is it a fault of Total Commander or I need to tune OS X settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your decompress tool passes the raw filenames directly to the VFS layer, it's not enough for the filenames to be in UTF-8. They must *also* be in [Normal Form D](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1173/_index.html). Having the filenames in Normal Form C will end up having them mangled in the VFS layer.

Comment: That URI no longer points to anything meaningful